# Python, curve fitting

Tags: python, list, recursion, curve-fitting

I want to fit a series of Gaussian function from which I do not know before hand how many are required. This is my current solution.

```
def gauss_recursive(x,max_value,pos,std):
    if len(pos)==1:
        return gauss(x,max_value,pos,std)
    else:
        return gauss_recursive(x,max_value[:-1],pos[:-1],std[:-1])+gauss(x,max_value[-1],pos[-1],std[-1])

def gauss(x,max_value,pos,std):
    from numpy import exp
    return max_value*exp(-(x-pos)*(x-pos)/std/std)
```

I know round about the position, the std and the maximal value. Therefore, the fit will converge even in the case of many Gaussian funtions. However, I need the curve fit to pass a list or a tuple to my function. It automatically puts it to many single parameters when I start it:

```
fit_para,err = curve_fit(gauss_recursive,x,y,p0=[[1,5,7],[11,15,14],[2.5,2.5,2.5]])
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: gauss_recursive() takes 4 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

The same effect happens when I pass p0 as a tuple instead of a list.

Is there a way to bypass this problem? If yes how?

Here is the solution:

```
def gauss_recursive(x,*args):
    laenge=int(len(args)/3)
    if laenge==1:
        return gauss(x,args[0],args[1],args[2])
    elif laenge>1:
        from numpy import ones
        dummy=ones(len(args))
        dummy[laenge-1]=0
        dummy[2*laenge-1]=0
        dummy[-1]=0
        dummy2=[args[i] for i in range(laenge*3) if dummy[i]==1]
        return gauss_recursive(x,*dummy2)+gauss(x,args[laenge-1],args[2*laenge-1],args[-1])
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: I think no arguments were passed in the input. Check that.

Comment: I do not completely know what you mean. However, If i start it like this, it will start my function. However, it converts the list to single elements. 

fit_para,err = curve_fit(gauss_recursive,x,y,p0=[[1,],[11],[2.5]])

Comment: gauss_recursive() is a function, where you need to pass 4 values. But in `fit_para,err = curve_fit(gauss_recursive,x,y,p0=[[1,],[11],[2.5]]) ` its empty or wrong format for input.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of this thats why I am asking. I tried to input a list or a tuple so that I have the right amount of input parameters. However, the curve fit funtion changes this to single variables. The example  fit_para,err = curve_fit(gauss_recursive,x,y,p0=[[1],[11],[2.5]]) had a comma too much. Despite this is normally starts gauss_recursive. I am aware that gauss_recursive breaks as it requires lists at input.But it starts.